# jQuery Mobile: How to run a callback-function before $.mobile.changePage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm setting up a mobile app with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. What I want to do is that when I click link with id "news_link" I want jQuery to fetch data from database and put it to jQm's collapsible set. In my solution, I've wanted to use $.mobile.changePage inside callback functions because I want to wait until the data has been fetched and put inside the container before the code changes page. 
Here's the code:

```
$(function() { 
  $('#news_link').click(function(){
    loadNewsFromDB(function(){
       $.mobile.changePage( $("#news"), { transition: "slideup"} );
    });
});
```

loadNewsFromDB is PhoneGap's SQLite database function which would fetch the data with more callback functions from database. The contents would be put to desired container with .html-function

```
function loadNewsFromDB(){
//some code here
theDB.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(sqlStr, [], onLoadNewsSuccess, onLoadNewsError);
},onTxError, onTxSuccess);

function onLoadNewsSuccess(tx, results){
    //some code here
    $("#newsSet").html(htmlCodeAndContentToPut);
```

Html is jQm's basic ui-modules:

```
<!-- some html code here --!>
<div data-role="page" id="news">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="newsSet" data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true">
```

With debugging I know that the code work up until it works very well unti it arrives to $.mobile.changePage-function. Somehow it doesn't change the page. I've checked the function it works well in other occasions, but not inside callback-functions.

I would be very grateful if someone would give me a hand am I not seeing something obviously wrong or is something more specific? What other workarounds there is for fetching the data from SQLite, waiting for data to be fetched, putting the data to container and then changing the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I never had problems with **`$.mobile.changePage`** on callback-function
  from **Ajax**, so it is possible to change page from a
  callback-function
- You call the `loadNewsFromDB` function with a function as a
  parameter.
   But I can't see where/how you are using this parameter
  on the `loadNewsFromDB` function itself. Don't you have to define the
  parameter on the `loadNewsFromDB` function? 
   After defining the callback-function, you should call it when your data is ready.
- I would try to use the **`$.mobile.changePage`** directly in your `onLoadNewsSuccess` function.

I believe that the code should look like this:

```
function loadNewsFromDB(callback){
//some code here
theDB.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(sqlStr, [], function(tx, result) {
            ...some code here...;
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }    
        },onLoadNewsError);
},onTxError, onTxSuccess);
```

---

Edit:
To answer the question in the comments:

- In your `$(function()` code, you are adding listener for the
  `$('#news_link').click` event.
- In this listener, you tell Jquery to call `loadNewsFromDB` function and
  to send it the following callback-function as a parameter: `function(){ $.mobile.changePage( $("#news"), { transition: "slideup"}`.

Sending the callback function is not enough, you should use it (call it) in your code.
To use it, I did the following:

- Changed the function definition **`function loadNewsFromDB(callback)`**
  now, it does have a new paramter: **`callback`** (which is the name you can use to call back your callback-function).
- In your `loadNewsFromDB` function, you are calling the
  **`transaction`** function, and send it 3 parameters: **inline function**, onTxError, onTxSuccess.
  your **inline function** just call the `tx.executeSql` function and send it 4 parameters: `sqlStr, [], onLoadNewsSuccess, onLoadNewsError`.
  I changed the third parameter.
  Instead of calling the `onLoadNewsSuccess` function, I **wrote the needed function inline**
- In the inline function, I checked if the callback function exist `if (callback)`
  If it exist, I called it! **`callback();`**
  calling the callback function, should change the page...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm quite newbie to jQuery so I don't know the exact syntax of callback functions, but at least according to W3CSchools and several other sources, the callback function is called by the `function(function(){});` So that is the callback-function, not parameter to my understanding. And I've actually tried putting the `$.mobile.changePage` inside onLoadsSuccess which ended up in bad html-markup in the destination page. The result of bad html markup is one reason why I'm investigating $.mobile.changePage -function as a callback function.

Comment: @Jugi84, Did you tried the code I wrote?    I just moved your `onLoadNewsSuccess` into the executeSql function...    Please give it a try...

Comment: One more question: how should I define / use the callback-function in that case? I thought that jQuery would automatically add the callback-function to called function if the function is called with callback. Now when I look at the code you provided, I'm a bit lost on how to use that. Does the above example with  $.mobile.changePage work with that code as well? Should I rename callback in the `loadNewsFromDB(callback)` to something else?

Comment: @Jugi84 - I updated the answer and add detailed explanation. hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, not it's clear.. and it WORKS! Although one minor thing with the whole approach is that because I use jQm's collapsible sets, they don't show up right. But that's most likely due to DOM so I would need to move that code to `pagebeforechange` event.. Have to think about different approaches. Thank you so much for your help, I learned a lot from you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean right before the changePage fires?

Then use the `pagebeforechange` event, which is triggered right before the `changePage`. I'm using this:

```
  $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
  // do stuff
  console.log( e )
  console.log( data )
  });
```

for all my changePage redirects. The `data` object will contain all changePage parameters (like toPage, options.fromPage...), so you can pretty much re-config the changePage call to your need.

**EDIT**: 
Also beware this event fires twice if `pushstate` is enabled. One event is triggered by the actual transition (on hashChange), this will pass the `toPage` you are going to as `string`. The 2nd event will be triggered by pushState and will pass the `toPage` as `object`. You can define what to when by checking for:

```
 typeof data.toPage == 'string'
```

**EDIT**: 
In your specific case, I would `preventDefault()` the original `changePage` depending on how long it takes to fetch the data from your database. It would probably be best to `preventDefault`, `trigger your database call` from inside pageBeforeChange and when you have the data loaded, `trigger` a new changePage. For more info see this [example](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html) from the JQM docs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer frequent. Actually, that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out now :)